# Scipy io read wavfile error

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, wav, audio-processing

Whenever I try to read a .wav file, the following error comes.
I have searched everywhere but had no progress upon this.

**CODE:**

```
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sr, y = sp.io.wavfile.read(MY_FILENAME)
print sr
```

**ERROR:**

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/io/wavfile.py", line 252, in read
    fmt_chunk = _read_fmt_chunk(fid, is_big_endian)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/io/wavfile.py", line 94, in _read_fmt_chunk
    raise ValueError("Unknown wave file format")
  ValueError: Unknown wave file format
```

**Update:**

After I tried converting my file as suggested by @velikodniy using sox:

```
sox MY_FILENAME.wav MY_FILENAME.wav
```

But it throws another warning:

```
sox WARN wav: Premature EOF on .wav input file
```

And now if I try to play the original .wav file, it says unsupported format in the media player(previously it was playing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WAVs may contain audio data in different formats. For example, MP3.`scipy.io.wavfile.read` can read only PCM and floating point formats (WAVE_FORMAT_PCM and WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT, to be exact) at the moment.

So you must convert your audio file with an audio editor (e.g. Audacity or sox).

Comment: @velikodnly, u mean to convert from wav to wav using sox?

Comment: Yes, I do. Sox supports a wide range of internal WAV formats. Such as  μ-law, A-law and so on. Maybe your file contains data encoded with one of them. Unfortunately, sox doesn't support mp3 inside WAVs.

Comment: it still throws a warning and now the file is not playing even in the media player

Comment: Could you test your program with [WAV files from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV#WAV_file_audio_coding_formats_compared)?

Comment: I've just tested. `sp.io.wavfile.read` works fine with `11k16bitpcm.wav`.

Comment: i found the solution, by converting my files to .ogg format and back to .wav, and it worked!!!

Comment: i had tested sp.io.wavfile.read with harvard audio files provided for testing, but it was not working for any of my .wav files

Answer (score 2):

I tried many solutions, but I only had success with the following steps:

1. Goto to the site: https://audio.online-convert.com/convert-to-wav ;
2. Upload your file ;
3. In **Optional settings** change **Change bit resolution** to **16 bit** ;
4. Click in **Start Conversion** and download your converted file;
5. Try open again with **scipy.io.wavfile.read(...)**;

Answer (score 0):

I converted the wav file to specific format using code and the error got resolved.

```
import soundfile as sf
y, s = librosa.load(pwd+'\\ans.wav', sr=48000)
sf.write('audio_test_1.wav', y, s, "PCM_24")

rate, data = read(pwd+'\\audio_test_1.wav')
```